# bashrc function, git commit -m with spaces

Tags: bash, terminal, git, bashrc

Currently I have this and it works as expected if I use it like `addcommit 'test commit'` but if I use it as `addcommit test commit` it only sees the first word `test`. Ideally I'd like to have the functionality of `addcommit test commit` and it executing `git add . && git commit -m 'test commit'`

```
addcommit()
{   
    git add . && git commit -m "$1"
}
```

PS. I don't understand how the `"$1"` works in this case, maybe that would be a good starting point to understanding how this should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `"$1"` with `"$*"`.

And in order to be completely safe against `IFS` traps:

```
addcommit()
{
   local IFS=' '
   git add . && git commit -m "$*"
}
```

This is a case where an alias could help, and allow the commit message to contain any character:

```
alias addcommit='_m=$(fc -nl -0); git add . && git commit -m "${_m#*addcommit }" #'

addcommit $foo * $bar
# will use the literal "$foo * $bar" message, without expanding it
```

(works in bash and ksh93)